# PostgreSQL: Find percentages of total_films_rented

Tags: postgresql

The code below gives me the following results

```
Early: 7738
Late: 6586
On Time: 1720
```

How would I take this a step further and add a third column that finds the percentages?

Here is a link to the ERD and database set-up: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/

```sql
WITH
    t1
    AS
    (
        SELECT *, DATE_PART('day', return_date - rental_date) AS days_rented
        FROM rental
    ),

    t2
    AS
    (
        SELECT rental_duration, days_rented,
            CASE WHEN rental_duration > days_rented THEN 'Early'
      WHEN rental_duration = days_rented THEN 'On Time'
      ELSE 'Late'
      END AS rental_return_status
        FROM film f, inventory i, t1
        WHERE f.film_id = i.film_id AND t1.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
    )

SELECT rental_return_status, COUNT(*) AS total_films_rented
FROM t2
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a window function with one CTE table (instead of 2):

```
WITH raw_status AS (
  SELECT rental_duration - DATE_PART('day', return_date - rental_date) AS days_remaining
    FROM rental r
    JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id=i.inventory_id
    JOIN film f on f.film_id=i.film_id
  )
SELECT CASE WHEN days_remaining > 0 THEN 'Early'
            WHEN days_remaining = 0 THEN 'On Time'
            ELSE 'Late' END AS rental_status,
       count(*),
       (100*count(*))/sum(count(*)) OVER () AS percentage
FROM raw_status
GROUP BY 1;
 rental_status | count |     percentage      
---------------+-------+---------------------
 Early         |  7738 | 48.2298678633757168
 On Time       |  1720 | 10.7205185739217153
 Late          |  6586 | 41.0496135627025679
(3 rows)
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to get the sum of the count column (`sum(count(*)) over ()`), then just divide the count by that (`count(*)/sum(count(*)) over ()`). Multiply by 100 to make it a percentage.

```
psql (12.1 (Debian 12.1-1))
Type "help" for help.

testdb=# CREATE TABLE faket2 AS (
SELECT 'early' AS rental_return_status UNION ALL
SELECT 'early' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ontime' UNION ALL
SELECT 'late');
SELECT 4
testdb=# SELECT
  rental_return_status,
  COUNT(*) as total_films_rented,
  (100*count(*))/sum(count(*)) over () AS percentage
FROM faket2
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
 rental_return_status | total_films_rented |     percentage      
----------------------+--------------------+---------------------
 early                |                  2 | 50.0000000000000000
 late                 |                  1 | 25.0000000000000000
 ontime               |                  1 | 25.0000000000000000
(3 rows)
```